# How to solve this Differential Equation without ProductLog in Mathematica?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, equation, dsolve

I'm trying to solve a Differential Equation using Mathematica to check whether the result I get is equal to the result I got by solving the equation by hand.

However, Mathematica gives me an answer including `ProductLog` which doesn't make sense to me.

Here is my differential equation:

```
y'[x] == x^2 + y[x]^2)/(x*y[x] - x^2)
```

This is my input to Mathematica:

```
DSolve[y'[x] == (x^2 + y[x]^2)/(x*y[x] - x^2), y[x], x]
```

This is the answer I got:

```
{{y[x] -> -x - 2 x ProductLog[-(E^(-(1/2) - C[1]/2)/(2 Sqrt[x]))]}}
```

The answer I got by solving by hand is:

```
y = xLn|((x+y)^2)/(x)| + Cx
```

C is the constant of integration.

Answer (score 0):

Use Mathematica to solve for y in the solution you found by hand.  The result involves ProductLog and looks very much like the soluiton Mathematica gives for your differential equation.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).